# WebService feito com NuSoap em PHP. Não consigo acessar no Java

Tags: php, java, soap

Desenvolvi um WebService em PHP, utilizando a biblioteca NuSoap. O Webservice já está hospedado e funcionando. Quando desenvolvo um cliente usando PHP, seja usando NuSoap ou usando a classe nativa soap do PHP, consigo usar o Webservice sem problemas. Mas quando tento usar o webservice num cliente java (através de wsdl), recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: tag XML
>   inesperada: esperava {}enviarNotaResponse, mas encontrou:
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}enviarNotaResponse

Já estou quebrando a cabeça pesquisando uma solução, mas caso alguém possa me dar alguma pista, agradeço.

Comment: Se não me engando a exceção foi traduzida para o português. É melhor que ela esteja exatamente como foi mostrada no log, pois fica mais fácil de encontrar situações relacionadas na Web.

Comment: Você consegue consumir esse webservice usando o [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)? O SoapUI é feito totalmente em Java. Veja se consegue. e poste para nós o resultado.

Answer (score 4):

O teu erro original deverá andar dentro destas linhas:

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: unexpected XML tag.
>   expected: {}enviarNotaResponse
>   but found: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}enviarNotaResponse

Resumidamente, está a indicar que o resultado obtido não é o esperado para o caminho indicado no lado do cliente.

Verifica o teu endereço, deverá estar incompleto ou conter algum erro de digitação.

Comment: Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça, descobri que estava faltando declarar os parâmetros URN ao registrar a função no WebService. Agora consigo acessar o serviço tanto em Java quanto em C#. Grato.